# Creating a Generic Jenkins Deployment Template Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I would like to define a deployment (CD) template that is capable of wrapping build (CI) jobs of various types. I would like the CD template to be completely ignorant of how the downstream CI job is built.

So far my best solution is to define an auxiliary template which is an attribute of the CD template. This auxiliary template includes a reference to the CI job (via the 'select item' type) and a text attribute 'branch'. I found that for the most part this is enough info to trigger the CI job, but is there a better way to do this?

Ideally I would like to be able to define the CI job's parameters directly in the CD job's configuration without needing to have the auxiliary template middle man.

EDIT:

Here's an example of how I'm calling a downstream build job in a different template:

```
parameterList = []
parameterList.add(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('stashRepo', stash))
parameterList.add(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('branch', branch))
parameterList.add(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('configDir', configDir))
parameterList.add(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('jdkVersion', jdkVersion))
build job: configBuildJob.buildJob.getFullName(), parameters: parameterList
```

The problem with this is the template makes the assumption that these build jobs have these exact parameters. It would be nice to be able to somehow set them in the templates configuration instead, so that I don't have to make assumptions about the downstream jobs in my code.

Comment: So.. the question is?

Comment: Is this the best solution? Am I missing a pipeline concept that would make this more straightforward?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a better way to integrate the CI job with the CD job. If I could surface the CI job's inputs directly in the CD job's configuration that would be great. Or if there was a way to enforce an 'interface' for the CI job, such that I could guarantee it would accept specific build parameters.

Comment: Parameterized jobs?

Comment: Could you improve you're question with a simpified example? How does your template looks like? I have posted an approach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070068/jenkins-pipeline-template that shows how to create a template using a Jenkins shared library. I think if you would use a scripted pipeline as template it could be possible to add stages and additional inputs of the build job as parameters to the template method. Another (easier) approach could be to have separate build pipelines that trigger a common deploy pipeline...

Comment: @Philip only problem with having the build pipeline trigger a common deploy pipeline is you would have several different apps as rows in your pipeline. I think it would be confusing which is being deployed.

Comment: @StephenKing yeah the build job would be parameterized. I would want the pipeline that wraps it to be able to call that build job with all of its parameters, and then allow the user to promote it up through higher environments after it's built.

Problem is supplying the parameters is tough to script in the template unless you know that the build jobs will always be called with the exact same parameters.

Comment: @Philip I edited my original question with a short example, hopefully that helps clarify a little.