# How do i run multiple Jenkins Pipelines in parallel and send environment variables to each?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple clients, all who need the same pipeline run but with different variables. My idea would be to do this:

1. Have a pipeline that does everything needed to build/package/deploy/verify for a client - and that takes env variables
2. Have a way to call that pipeline and pass it env variables at runtime
3. Have a way to call that pipeline multiple times with diff env variables but with one call (maybe a pipeline that loops over an array of variables)

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches - it depends on your use case which fits best. From the top of my head:

1. Create a pipeline job with parameters and trigger it manually/or per api for each client. A sample taken from https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-directives :

   ```
   pipeline {
       agent any
       parameters {
           string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
       }
       stages {
           stage('Example') {
               steps {
                   echo "Hello ${params.PERSON}"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Have one pipeline job that triggers another pipeline job (once for each client) also using parameters. The parent job can have a stage for each client:

   ```
   stage ('Build client A') {
       build job: 'common-pipeline-job-for-clients', 
           parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value: 'some value')]
   }
   ```
3. Create a pipeline template and use the template to create a pipeline for each client - as described here: [Jenkins pipeline template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070068/jenkins-pipeline-template)