# Sharing Conventional Jenkinsfile in Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to share pipeline definitions in shared libraries and use these definitions in multibranch pipeline jobs?

We're trying to build a conventional declarative pipeline for all of our repositories to share. Each repository would essentially have the same `Jenkinsfile`. As such, we've created a shared pipeline step that's basically just `conventionalPipeline`, so each repository's `Jenkinsfile` would be a single line to call this step.

This idea is stopped dead in its tracks with `RejectedAccessException`s because multibranch pipeline projects run in the sandbox (there's no way to prevent the sandbox). [This issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28178) tracks the behavior within the Jenkins project.

We can trust `conventionalPipeline` *and everything it does*, but because it calls untrusted methods we can't call it within multibranch pipelines. We could whitelist all the methods it calls, but this would open up the security holes that the sandbox tries to close.

There are two options I see - curious if I've overlooked something

1. Modify jenkins somehow to allow an untrusted method to become trusted and allow all subsequent method calls by that method to be implicitly trusted
2. Allow multibranch pipeline definitions to be defined in the jenkins config for the repository rather than in SCM, and let this job run outside the sandbox

Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You can use the [Pipeline Shared Groovy Library plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin) to have a library that all your projects share in a git repository. In the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl) you can read about it in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins pipeline template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070068/jenkins-pipeline-template)

Comment: Yup already doing that, but a multibranch pipeline project must get its Jenkinsfile from SCM, and the Jenkinsfile is run in sandbox mode. Our pipline plugin makes untrusted calls, plus we don't want/need to have more than one `Jenkinsfile` at all, we'd really like to be able to specify the Jenkinsfile in the multibranch pipeline config and just have that Jenkinsfile be the single-line call to our shared library step/var. Hope this clarifies.